# Show in a Web application R scripts graphics

Tags: java, r, web-applications

I am making a Web Application with Struts, and I would like to show a graphic in one of my JSP (or wherever). I would like to excute an RScript, and then show the graphic.

I have reed that with Shiny you can make a web application, but I don't think I could integrate with my Web Application

Any idea would be awesome (maybe export the graphic)

Cheers.